# SyntaxError when using a semicolon after import in Python

Tags: python

I want to execute the following command:

```
python -c "import os, random, string; for _ in range(30): os.mkdir(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(3, 10))))"
```

But I'm getting:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os, random, string; for _ in range(30): os.mkdir(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(3, 10))))
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does this error occur?

Same code with linebreaks and without the semicolon:

```
import os, random, string

for _ in range(30):
    os.mkdir(''.join(
        random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(3, 10))
        ))
```

Comment: Python needs white space, so when you one-line it, it doesn't know what your indentation is

Comment: @MikeTung not 100% true, `import time; x = time.time(); print(x)` works fine, the real answer is in the dup link from Vaultah